# wordpress 404 error page issue

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am working on a wordpress website and the permalinks are set to default i.e. like http://www.example.com/?p=213. If the page Id or Post Id is not valid then only it goes to the 404.php file of my theme else if I try to check 404 page for some random page like http://www.example.com/somepagename then It takes me to the host's 404 error page. How do I make this go to my theme's 404 page as well ? It is a trouble, I hope you guys will help me out here. Thank You in advance

Comment: issue with the permalink, change the permalink type under settings in admin panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### About short heads up on HTTP Request Processing

The HTTP request is processed in the following sequence

1. Browser sends a request to server
2. Server receives the request
3. Checks for the Page requested 
   IF FOUND
      Display Page
   IF NOT FOUND
      Display 404 Page

### What's happening under the hood

In case of http://www.example.com/?p=213 the page is found in the server hence the server doesn't display the 404 page. However, when wordpress processes the query string **p=213**, it identifies that no such page/post exists and displays the wordpress 404 page.

In case of http://www.example.com/somepagename the page is not found in the server hence the server itself displays the 404 page even before wordpress can process it.

### Solution

You have to make the 404 page of the wordpress (appropriate 404 for the selected theme) as the 404 page of the webserver too. You can also link a php page to the webserver error message which would redirect to appropriate 404 pages based on themes and other factors.

Comment: Hi @Coder X Thank u very much for your such a nice and explanatory answer but let me know how can I get access to my webserver error page or error message. Tell me how do I resolve this problem

Comment: In your web hosting site _cpanel_ you'll have a link for **Error Pages**. Find and click on that link, that should take you to a page with the list of common error codes. From there you can go and change the error page for each HTTP codes.